# capifony fail on assetic:install --env=prod

Tags: php, symfony, deployment, assetic, capifony

```
    executing "sh -c 'cd /var/www/html/xxx/staging/releases/xxxxx && php app/console assets:install web --env=prod'"
    servers: ["xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"]
    [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] executing command
    command finished in 124ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /var/www/html/xxx/staging/releases/xxxxx; true"
    servers: ["xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"]
    [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] executing command
    command finished in 255ms
failed: "sh -c 'sh -c '\\''cd /var/www/html/xxx/staging/release/xxx && php app/console assets:install web --env=prod'\\'''"
```

I am having the above error while deploying my applicaiton to the server. it has been working for the past 2 years but now it fails. parameters.yml is obviously there with everything inside and `logger.level = Logger::MAX_LEVEL` is properly set.

It is very frustrating because running assets:install or assetic:dump works on localhost for `--env=prod` and dev and the error message on the server does not even give any additional information.

please help

Comment: Hi @sedigo have you find the problem? How do you debug your situation? Is always an headache debug this situation...

Comment: Hi @Matteo I fixed it by just checking my code until I see where something is mistyped. I cannot take my answer as the solution because still I could not see the error details in the deployment process. I was just lucky to get to that line with the error in my code but there is no way you will be able to go through all your changes to check where the error is. It needs to display all the errors while deploying.

Answer (score 2):

You can debug your procedure deploy by launch the cap task as:

```
 cap -dv deploy
```

and execute yourself on the server command line the problematic task (don't do that to capifony, take the task waiting meanwhile, otherwise it will rollback the execution without prompt you the error)

Hope this help